# AWS workspaces user and password definition

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-workspaces

My Question:
How can I create an AWS workspace for a user which is not defined in an Active Directory ?

Description:
I understand that WorkSpaces may be built only for users defined in a given active directory (AD):
either on premise AD (via AD connector);
OR AWS AD (amazon directory service);
OR AWS simple AD.

I would like to create a workspace for a user defined in (for example) AWS IAM or AWS cognito.
Can it be done ?
If so how ?

Thanks :-) !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible.

From [Manage Directories for Amazon WorkSpaces - Amazon WorkSpaces](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/workspaces/latest/adminguide/manage-workspaces-directory.html):

> Amazon WorkSpaces uses a directory to store and manage information for your WorkSpaces and users. You can use one of the following options:
>
> - AD Connector — Use your existing on-premises Microsoft Active Directory. Users can sign into their WorkSpaces using their on-premises credentials and access on-premises resources from their WorkSpaces.
> - Microsoft AD — Create a Microsoft Active Directory hosted on AWS.
> - Simple AD — Create a directory that is compatible with Microsoft Active Directory, powered by Samba 4, and hosted on AWS.
> - Cross trust — Create a trust relationship between your Microsoft AD directory and your on-premises domain.

Comment: Thank you John :-) I thought Amazon AWS treats Cognito as "kind of" active directory.
So I expected that WorkSpaces will be able to use Cognito. 
Is my assumption wrong ?